# How can I ensure Realm schema is identical across Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, realm

I'm looking at using Realm for a project where we have both iOS and Android clients.

It looks like there's not any way to ensure that the database schemas are the same on both platforms, such that the data stores could be exchanged between them. Since the schema is effectively defined in code, how can I ensure they remain compatible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Realm browser can generate Models from existing Realm files in multiple languages. So maybe you could create a realm file on one platform and then use the browser to generate the counterpart for the other language?

Comment: This is probably your best bet. Right now there is no automated way of ensuring that model classes on both iOS and Android are actually compatible. Key things to remember is that names and types will have to match. The order of fields is not important.

Comment: Thanks ast for the answer and Christian for confirming!

Answer (score 0):

The realm documentation says that Realm files are cross platform.

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#finding-a-realm-file

You can follow the instructions in that section to make sure your schemas are the same.

Comment: It looks like that lets me test that the schemas are the same after the fact, but it doesn't help me make sure the schemas are the same to start with.

Comment: Are you not in control of the schemas to start with?  It may then be easiest to convert to your favorite text format like JSON, and compare the structures, using tree traversal.