# Make realm.io db file on a linux server

Tags: realm

I need to store on a mobile device (iOS/Android) more that 100k records with several tables (many-to-many relations). 
Right now I store them in sqlite/CoreData. The sync process is slow (http->json->db). I want to use realm and pre-populate realm db file on a server (http->db).

Questions:

1) Is realm db file binary compatible among platforms?

2) Can I make realm db file on a linux server? Which realm-SDK should I use?

I wish realm developers read this!

UPDATE:

found related thread
[How can I ensure Realm schema is identical across Android and iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091489/how-can-i-ensure-realm-schema-is-identical-across-android-and-ios)

so, I can answer for myself:

1) "The realm documentation says that Realm files are cross platform." https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#finding-a-realm-file

2) "The Realm browser can generate Models from existing Realm files in multiple languages." You can use realm-cocoa and build your tool on linux server, apt-get install gcc gobjc gnustep-devel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update #2

We released the [Node.js SDK](https://realm.io/news/first-object-database-realm-node-js-server/), which can be used on the server-side to access Realms.

This however doesn't include the new synchronization capabilities though. Server-side access to synced Realms remains exclusive to the Enterprise Edition of the Realm Mobile Platform.

### Update

We released the [Realm Mobile Platform](https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-platform/). You can use this to real-time synchronize Realm files served via the Realm Object Server, over a custom protocol on top of HTTP which will only transmit the deltas.

For the Enterprise Edition of the Realm Mobile Platform, we offer a Node.js binding, which can be used for server-side access.

Realm's [Core](https://github.com/realm/realm-core) is now open-source.

### Original Answer

There isn't really a suitable binding for servers yet - not if you don't want to run an OS X machine. I don't know about experiences with building Realm's Objective-C binding on GNUstep's alternative FoundationKit implementation, but you will likely run into issues, where it will be hard to assist you, because that's a completely untested configuration.

Note though that this is generally an issue, we're investigating. We're not yet at the point, where we can expose an official C++ binding / a public API of the underlying Core, which is the shared codebase between Cocoa and Java.

Comment: Thank's Marius, I'll wait the public official C++ binding if you do so

Comment: But just making sure: it's not directly around the corner. We don't have anything like an ETA for that at this point.

Comment: Has this changed with 2.0?

Comment: Yes, this changed indeed drastically! We've heard you and others and offer now synchronization as part of our platform, you can run yourself on OS X & Linux.

Comment: @marius that means you already have some high-level cross-platform binding for a particular language? Is there any milestone to publish it as well? looking forward to use realm on linux without the object server

Comment: OK, I see no high-level linux api now except realm-object-store. What you have in the sync-server is a closed source C/C++ app which does the job and only binds to nodejs. I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: We strive to not disappoint and get cool stuff out as quickly as possible. But at the time of writing you are absolutely right that the Object Server is closed source. We would love to make a C++ SDK, and are prioritising this along all the other feature requests we get. So we encourage you to vote on the github issues for C++ https://github.com/realm/realm-core/issues/1954 and explain your usecase - unless you have a man year to spare on helping out of course :wink:

Comment: I updated my answer for the release of the Node.js SDK. Thanks to @ReDetection for pointing this out.